# WooCommerce - a single product url without permalink

Tags: woocommerce, permalinks

I recently discovered that a single product in my WooCommerce shows up in search results without its permalink. I cannot find this product anywhere, and therefore I cannot fix the permalink issue.

The link should read as: **/nb/butikk/adheseal-2/**

But it reads as: **/nb/?product_variation=adheseal-2**

Which of course just reroutes to the main page. I cannot find this entry in the system so I have noway of fixing the issue. It's a single post problem because every other item works as expected. Not just this particular link. Seeing as clicking the link doesn't work, I cannot find the post ID either.

I have tried to clean up the DB, resetting permalinks etc. but to no awail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was a cache issue that prevented the permalink update.